# Ubuntu 18.04 apt-get error

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

Ubuntu 18.04 apt-get error

When I run apt-get in terminal I receive these errors:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/blahota/texstudio/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/q-quark/equalx/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have no clue what to do (any ideas?). Your help is SO appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure what you are trying to GET is for your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: A quick look and it's easy to see that https://launchpad.net/~blahota/+archive/ubuntu/texstudio which stopped being supported in 2015, provides no support for a 2018-April (18.04) release. PPA's are 3rd party software sources, so all security, fitness for purpose checks are your responsibility.

Comment: As above an unfortunately it's the exact same situation for all the PPAs mentioned in the error message. You need to remove them all.

Comment: @ChanganAuto can you tell me how to remove them all?

Comment: @JoshMcCraney Software&Updates > Other Software is the GUI way and the easiest, IMO.

Comment: @ChanganAuto okay, so you're saying to remove all the ppa.launchpad options in the "Other Software" tab? I just want to make sure this is correct before I do anything stupid.

Comment: All the ones (3) mentioned in the error message, yes. Neither have content for Ubuntu 18.04.